# Magento Multi-language site, and SEO issue?

Tags: magento-1.9

First, let me clarify I'm not expert in Magento, and I had to use Magento due my supplier requirement, I think it's an awesome platforms but it's a bit tricky for people like me

I have a site that has 2 languages: English and Russian

My clients are all Russian, and for the front end I don't really need English interface.

But my supplier speaks English only, and he would need to upload the products on my behalf to my site, and then I will translate the products name and specification for the Russian version of the site.

I talked to several developers about some issue I have and got contracting answers from each one, and I would appreciate your thoughts to choose the right method.

The products titles in English is used by all the distributors, so if the item name is YYTTRR11, and google it, many websites will show up using the same title.

My questions are:

1- If I keep english and Russian in the front end, will the english website ranking of the site affect my Russian word ranking?

2- Is it better for the SEO to have one language only for the front end?

3- Is there any way to have English and Russian front end, but only Russian products to be found on search engines?
Edit
Stop Wanting Answers1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you setup two websites and separate the front view into two domains - one targeting the Russian market, the other targeting your English setup.

This will allow you to write custom descriptions, product names, using currency relevant to the branch of the site you are looking at. This should have a positive impact on your rankings as you do not have duplicate content on the two websites.

From an SEO perspective again this is beneficial more beneficial too for Russian speakers since they will be searching in Russian and more likely to discover your products.